# Are complete statistics always sufficient?

Tags: exponential-family, sufficient-statistics, point-estimation

> I know that a complete sufficient statistic $T$ is such that 
>   1) $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$, unknown parameter and 2) $T$ is complete.

So, is it always the case? If the answer is not, what could be an example of a complete but not sufficient statistic? Instead is it true in exponential family distributions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For completeness you need to consider only the distribution of the statistic $T$ (more correctly, the family of distributions indexed by $\theta$), whereas for sufficiency you need to consider the complete likelihood for $\theta$ as a function of the sample $X$; so it's trivial to come up with examples where $T$ isn't sufficient but is still complete:

- The constant statistic $T(X)=7$.
- Throw some of your data away & calculate your (previously complete &
  sufficient) test statistic on what's left. Suppose you've four
  observations $X_1,\ldots,X_4$ from a Gaussian with mean $\theta$ (& known standard deviation):
  $T(X)=\frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$ isn't sufficient for $\theta$ but is
  complete.
- Twice the sample mean from a random variable uniformly distributed between
  $0$ & $\theta$, $T(X)=\frac{2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$ (the method-of-moments estimator), is complete, but we know the sufficient statistic for
  $\theta$ is the sample maximum $X_{(n)}$.

See [Complete sufficient statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61990/17230) for a more interesting example—of a sufficient statistic that isn't complete.